# SQL left join with conditions from two tables

Tags: sql, left-join, ms-access-2010

Is there a way to combine the following queries Q1 and Q2 into one?

I believe it to be important to know the structure of the tables a, b & c:

- a.ID (auto), a.01 (1 letter)
- b.01 (1 letter), a.02 (1 digit number)
- c.ID (auto), c.01 (lookup from a.ID), c.02 (1 digit number)

All b.01 values will be present in a.01.

This is Q1:

```
SELECT a.ID, b.[02], b.[01]
FROM a, b
WHERE (((b.[01])=[a].[01]));
```

This is Q2:

```
SELECT Q1.*
FROM Q1 LEFT JOIN c ON [Q1].[ID]=[c].[01]
WHERE ((c.[02]) Is Null);
```

Comment: Removed the mysql tag because `[` is clearly MS Access and not MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
SELECT a.ID, b.[02], b.[01]
FROM a INNER JOIN b ON b.[01] = a.[01]
LEFT JOIN c ON a.id = c.[01]
WHERE c.[02] IS NULL
```